# React Query skip query when parameter is empty

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-query

I am dealing with react query problem, I have separate file with all the queries:

```
const useFetchApTableQuery = (date: string): UseQueryResult => {
  const axiosClient = axios.create()

  const fetchApTableQuery = async (): Promise<AxiosResponse> => {
    const res = await axiosClient.get(`${API_ROUTES.apTable}?date=${date}`)
    return res.data.data.map((record: any) => APParser(record))
  }

  return useQuery([date], fetchApTableQuery, {

  })
}
```

and then iam calling my query in component like this

```
const APTablePage = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [selectedPeriod, setSelectedPeriod] = useState<string>('')
  const { data: tableData } = useFetchApTableQuery(selectedPeriod)

   ....
}
```

The problem is need useQuery to omit fetching data when selectedPeriod param is empty (selected period is also being fetched from api when component mounts so I don't have any default value to set for selected period). is there any possibility to make useQuery pass for example null to {data:tabledata} variable when selectedPeriod is empty string ?

Thank you :-)

I have tried dealing with this via useEffect but unfortunately I cannot call hooks in useffect

Answer (score 4):

You can set the [`enabled` property](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/migrating-to-react-query-3#if-set-the-queryoptionsenabled-option-must-be-a-boolean-truefalse) to be `true` when date is not empty

```
const useFetchApTableQuery = (date: string): UseQueryResult => {
  const axiosClient = axios.create()

  const fetchApTableQuery = async (): Promise<AxiosResponse> => {
    const res = await axiosClient.get(`${API_ROUTES.apTable}?date=${date}`)
    return res.data.data.map((record: any) => APParser(record))
  }

  return useQuery([date], fetchApTableQuery, {
    enabled: date.length > 0
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i'm not sure about my answer but we can disable a query from automatically running, you can use the

> { enabled: false }
> the optional object argument that you pass to customize all behaviors of react-query read more at the end  ,

```
useQuery([date], fetchApTableQuery, { enabled : false}) // this will always disabled .
useQuery([date], fetchApTableQuery, { enabled :  pram.length > 0}) // with condition enabled or disabled
```

the enable key is in scope whenever the function Component run you can pass to it any value outside the scope that control your fetching requests

i really encourage you to read the docs it's very simple to master ReacQuery ,have fun  ✋ !

https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/guides/disabling-queries

https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/guides/dependent-queries

Comment: Thank you  :-) !  ive been trying `skip` option but unsucessfully, but this works

Comment: alright congratulation  , Mark ✅ if whatever answer helps you to resolve the problem for other people like us to know and learn more !